# Computer not starting after suspend

Tags: suspend

I have Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming laptop. My computer doesn't start after suspend. I have to press the power key, turn it off and then turn it on back again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For the first option **NVIDIA Corporation Unknown** I changed the option from 'Using xorg server' to using NVIDIA driver.

After restart,the issue was solved.
My daughter had probably changed it while being naughty :)